# AngularJS Notify $watchCollection of changed model that $watch watches

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I have a $watch listening for an input, the calling a service to get some new data.
That returned data is also needed by a $watchCollection.

How can I notify a $watchCollection that a $watch has happened (and thus update scope)

My HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>A: <input type="text" ng-model="input"></p>
    <p>B: <input type="text" ng-model="output"></p>
</div>
```

My JS

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.$watch('input', function(newVal, oldVal){
    //go get some data from a service...
    var reallyNewVal = Date.now();

    $scope.input = reallyNewVal;
});
$scope.$watchCollection('[output]', function(output){
    //watch this, plus some other stuff too, omitted for simplicity
    $scope.output = $scope.input - 1391754634457;
});
}]);
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gC7Zr/

What I'm looking for is when $scope.input changes (due to $watch), $watchCollection also updates.
I don't want to put $scope.input into the $watchCollection, as it's comsuming a XHR request..

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here's another example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/n46rj/
As you change B, C gets updated. However, if you change A, C doesn't get updated. How can I force the $watchCollection 'update' ($digest?) when $watch is called?

Comment: why are you watching the ouput with $watchCollection?

Comment: exactly, the line $scope.output = $scope.input - 132365413 should be in input watch to accomplish what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

since output is dependent only on input, you can change it in the first `$watch`

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('input', function(newVal, oldVal){
        //go get some data from a service...
        var reallyNewVal = Date.now();

        $scope.input = reallyNewVal;
        $scope.output = $scope.input - 1391754634457;
    });

    $scope.$watchCollection('[output]', function(output){
        //watch some other stuff

    });
}]);
```